# Undertanding import in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype

I came across this source code.
I do not understand the first line:

`import type { a, b, c, d } from 'types'`

What is the difference with

`import { a, b, c, d } from 'types'`
Could you please explain? Thanks

```js
import type { a, b, c, d } from 'types'// not sure what it does
import { a, b, c, d } from 'types' // I am familar with this
```

Comment: Is there a comma after the word `type`?

Comment: no, no comma, the code works as expected, the missing of the comma is actually confusing me

Comment: the code use flowtype

Comment: Yes @Radex is correct, it should be using flowtype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not vanilla JavaScript `import` usage. This is probably Flow, or a closely-related transpiled language.

I found a blog post from the Flow project entitled [Announcing Import Type](https://flow.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types/). I don't know Flow, but it looks like a strictly-type superset of JavaScript. The `import type` statement is how you import type information about a class without importing the class itself. They give an example where you might want to declare stirctly-typed formal arguments in a function and need to import the appropriate types:

```
import type {Crayon, Marker} from 'WritingUtensils';
module.exports = function junkDrawer(x: Crayon, y: Marker): void {}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is importing type definitions from the file.

```
// Here you are importing the actual method, variable from the file.
import xyz from 'abc';`

// Here you are importing the type defination of xyz
import type { xyz } from 'abc';
```

Now if you want to use it as

`let a: xyz = new xyz();`

Answer (score -2):

From MDN, although the missing comas from OP is weird:

> Importing defaults: It is possible to have a default export (whether it
>   is an object, a function, a class, etc.). The import statement may
>   then be used to import such defaults.
>
> The simplest version directly imports the default:
>
> `import myDefault from '/modules/my-module.js';`
>
> It is also possible to
>   use the default syntax with the ones seen above (namespace imports or
>   named imports). In such cases, the default import will have to be
>   declared first. For instance:
>
> `import myDefault, {foo, bar} from '/modules/my-module.js'; // specific, named imports`

In other words, this will import the default as myDefault, and then import the named exports.